# 6v reading on a LiFePO4 18650

Tags: lifepo4

I have 2 charged LiFePO4, which should be between 2.5v and 3.6v both reading 6v. I think my meter is broken, but I just want to check: Is that possible?

Comment: Do you have a 9-volt or AA battery? Try measure that for a sanity check of you meter. Another possibility: does the battery have a boost-converter board on it?

Comment: @比尔盖子 I just measured a 12v wallwart and it reads 17v. I'm starting to get convinced it's the meter.

Comment: Although uncommon today, some old wallwarts are unregulated, getting a higher voltage under no-load is not unusual. Measuring a AA battery is a more definite test, you can just find a TV remote control and measure that.

Comment: Bad battery in your multimeter? It's very common for them to over-read measurements with low batteries.

Comment: @比尔盖子 AAAs seem to all measure 1.3-1.5v

Comment: Many multimeters have the lowest range of 3-volt/6-volt, perhaps this range on your meter is unaffected, so I guess a 9-volt battery is more useful...  Anyway, as @winny said, the most likely cause is bad battery in your meter. If the battery is low, the internal reference voltage goes down, your meter will detect a higher false voltage in measurements.